# Using Services in AngularJS to return object value to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to read names from the JSON file.        I first created without services using the only controller.But then to moved the business logic to services. I am not getting a clear idea that about how to return the $scope.mydata from service to the controller. 
        Not getting any output please help. Thank you.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
         <title></title>
         <!-- Add angularjs -->
         <!-- Add controller script-->
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('x2js', []);
            app.controller('ctrl',
               ['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
                $scope.data = function(){
                    myService.getData()
                }
            }]);
            app.service('myService', ['$http','$log', function($http,$log){
            this.getData = function(){
                $http({
                    url:"student.json",
                    method:"GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json"

                }).then(function(response){
                    $scope.myData = response.data.records;
                    $log.info($scope.post);
                    return($scope.myData);
                },function(response){
                    $log.error("Error occured");
                });
            }
        }])
       </script>
       </head>
       <body ng-app="x2js">
        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="x in Data">{{x.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the service, [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the promise created by the `.then` method:

```
app.service('myService', ['$http','$log', function($http,$log){
    this.getData = function(){
        ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ $http({
            url:"student.json",
            method:"GET",
            //dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: "application/json"
        }).then(function(response){
            var myData = response.data.records;
            //$log.info($scope.post);
            return(myData);
        },function(errorResponse){
            $log.error("Error occured "+errorResponse.status);
            //IMPORTANT
            throw response;
        });
    }
}])
```

In the controller, extract the data from the promise:

```
  app.controller('ctrl',
    ['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
        var promise =  myService.getData();

        promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }).catch(errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse,status);
            throw errorResponse;
        });

  }]);
```

The `.then` method of a promise *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues).<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)</sup>

In promise error handlers, it is important to re-throw the error response otherwise the rejected promise will be **converted** to a fulfilled promise that returns a value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) `$http` service return promise. You need to move your `then` functions into controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
         <title></title>
         <!-- Add angularjs -->
         <!-- Add controller script-->
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('x2js', []);
            app.controller('ctrl',
               ['$scope','myService', '$log',function($scope,myService, $log){

                   myService.getData().then(function(response){
                    $scope.data = response.data.records;
                    $log.info($scope.data);

                },function(response){
                    $log.error("Error occured");
                })
                }
            }]);
            app.service('myService', ['$http', function($http){
            this.getData = function(){
                retutn $http({
                    url:"student.json",
                    method:"GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json"

                });
            }
        }])
       </script>
       </head>
       <body ng-app="x2js">
        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="x in data">{{x.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Still got no output. :(

Comment: @AmitPhartiyal you used `Data` into html and in controller values assigned to `data` variable.

Comment: actually it's myData in his example

Comment: @pegla `myData` is in service. He used `data` in controller.

Comment: you are right, missed that all of the code is in service, I separate controllers/services/directives in different files so didn't see it.

Comment: You logged $scope.post instead of $scope.data in your answer.

Comment: @AmitPhartiyal i just copy paste code written into your service.