# Angular - view not updating after model changed after http request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, data-binding, angularjs-digest

I am writing an app with Angular 1.5, Ionic 1.3, and Cordova. Right now I am working on a part where the user will push a button, the app will store the time and geolocation in the localStorage and then post the data back to the server and update the view. The issue I am having is that in one situation the view is not updating after a model change.

I have tried a few things: $timeout, $rootScope, $q and nothing seems to fix the issue. It only happens on iOS and not on Android. I am also using this library to help with the geolocation process: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

I am aware of the 3rd party library issue where it may not be a part of the Angular digest cycle but I have wrapped it with $q and no luck: https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/top-5-technical-issues-large-sites-angularjs.html

I am posting the pseudo code here.

**view.html**

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
<ion-content>
            <span>{{ data.text }}</span>
            <span>{{ data.date }}</span>
            <span>{{ data.isSync }}</span>
            <button ng-click="showPopup()">Click</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('ViewController', ViewController);

    ViewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'GeoDataModelService'];

    function ViewController($scope, GeoDataModelService) {
        $scope.data = GeoDataModelService.value;
        $scope.showPopup = GeoDataModelService.showPopup();
    }

})();
```

**service.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('GeoDataModelService', GeoDataModelService);

    GeoDataModelService.$inject = [
        ...
    ];

    function GeoDataModelService(
        ...
        ) {

        //data model
        var dataModel = {
            isSync: true,
            text: null,
            date: null
        };

        return {
            value: dataModel,
            showPopup: showPopup
        };

        function showPopup() { //gets called
            $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'clock now ?',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'CONTINUE',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function () {
                        geoData();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'CANCEL',
                    type: 'button-default'
                }]
            });
        };

        function geoData() {
            getLocationServicesStatus()
                .then(geoServiceSuccessful)
                .catch(function(err) {});
        };

        function geoServiceSuccessful() { //gets called
            DataModelService.createRecord();
            sendDataToServerAfterGeoData();
        }

        function getLocationServicesStatus() {
            console.log(' getLocationServicesStatus');

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            //this is outside of angular
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(
                function (available) {
                    if (available) {
                        deferred.resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject(false);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(false);
                }
            );

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function updateDataModel(source) {
            console.log('source ', source); //this one is not null
            if (source != null) {
                dataModel.text = source.text;
                dataModel.date = source.date;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(dataModel)); //correct
            }
        }

        function sendDataToServerAfterGeoData() {

            //if offline just skip the server post 
            if (!navigator.onLine) {

                // trigger digest cycle
                $timeout(function () {
                    updateModelAfterRecord(); //this one works fine
                }, 0);

                return;
            }

            var clockins = DataModelService.load(); //load from local storage

            console.log(' * * * * * HERE WE GO * * * * * ');

            //this service returns an http promise
            DataModelService
                .sendLocalDataToService(clockins)
                .then(sendDataToServerAfterGeoDataSuccess)
                .then(getClockDataToServerAfterGeoSuccess)
                .catch(handleSendDeviceDataToServerFail);
        };

        function sendDataToServerAfterGeoDataSuccess() {
            console.log(' sendDataToServerAfterGeoDataSuccess ');
            //this service returns an http promise
            return DataModelService.getDataModelFromServer();
        }

        function getClockDataToServerAfterGeoSuccess(response) {
            console.log(' getClockDataToServerAfterGeoSuccess ', response);
            console.log('1 dataModel: ', dataModel);

            // $timeout not working here
            // $rootScope.asyncEval not working either
            // $rootScope.$apply threw an error

            console.log(' 2 dataModel: ', dataModel); //correct
            dataModel.isSync = true;
            updateDataModel(response); //goes through this code
            console.log('3 dataModel: ', dataModel); //correct
            console.log(' 4 dataModel: ', dataModel); //correct
            console.log('5 dataModel: ', dataModel); //correct

            return response; //tried to leave this out - no effect
        }

        function handleSendDeviceDataToServerFail(error) {
            console.log('handleSendDeviceDataToServerFail ', error);
            var clockins = DataModelService.load();
            dataModel.isSync = false;
            updateDataModel(clockins); //this works
        }

        function updateModelAfterRecord() {
            dataModel.isSync = false;
            var data = DataModelService.load();
            updateDataModel(data);
        }


    }

})();
```

I added a watcher to see if the data is changing:

```
$scope.$watch('data.text', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(' new val', newVal); //this is correct
});
```

Comment: Use [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: [Possible duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46380494/3148590)

Comment: I am using a http promise but I cannot post the entire code of my app on one question.